# Refactoring Implicit Interface Implementation into Explicit Interface Implementation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, refactoring

I have inherited a C# code base; there are couple of classes that are implementing multiple interfaces and also have additional public methods. I want to refactor these classes such that implicit interface public methods are refactored to explicit interface implementations so that I can find out easily what additional public methods exisits and can decide something about them accordingly..

Is there (preferably free) refactoring addin (I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate) or tool available that can do this?

Comment: Would I be correct in saying that what you want to know is which public methods are not part of implicit interface implementations?

Comment: Yes; this is my first requirement; but eventually I would also like explicit implementation too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resharper (although not free) shows an icon when a method implements an interface.  If there is no icon it is explicit.

[image]

Comment: Resharper (now) also indicates the icon when the implementation is explicit. (VS2012, RS7.1.1)